# Reading integers while break condition not met in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge

This is a drill from the Programming Principles and Practice Using C++. I managed to get it to work but somehow it doesn't feel right to me. I 'd appreciate any pointers on how to simplify/improve the solution.

Especially when it comes to best check if '|' was entered. I feel that creating two extra string variables and then converting them to int using `std::stoi` is very inefficient. I am new to C++ so please excuse the ignorance. Appreciate any feedback.

#### Question

> Write a program that in a while loop reads 2 integers and prints them. Carry on until the user enters '|'.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(){
    int a, b;
    std::string _a, _b;
    while (true){
        std::cout << "Enter two numbers." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> _a >> _b;
        if (_a == "|" || _b == "|"){break;};
        a = std::stoi(_a);
        b = std::stoi(_b);
        std::cout << "You entered " << a << " and " << b << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        std::cout << "Enter two numbers." << std::endl;
```

You are looking to accept *integers*, not just numbers (i.e. \$1.0, 1e0, 0b1, 0x1\$).

Avoid `std::endl`.  [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) inserts a newline character into an output sequence and flushes it as if by calling `stream.put(stream.widen('\n'))` followed by `stream.flush()`.  If you just want to insert a newline character, then stream `'\n'`.

```
std::cout << "Enter two integers:\n"; // can append it on C strings
```

---

```
        std::cin >> _a >> _b;
```

Think about how you want to handle inputs.  You are expecting 2 integers, but what if they pass you one integer? No integers (or send end-of-file)? For those cases, you should check if the value was read successfull (see 10.10 in your book).

When a value cannot be extracted from the stream, the streamable types in C++ will typically set `std::ios::failbit`.  When [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is the type being extracted, a failure to extract leaves the data in the string unchanged.  For other types, like the numeric types, the extraction operation will assign 0 on failure.

If the stream enters a fail state, you won't be able to extract from it until you [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error flag.  Not clearing the error flag would result in an infinite loop once the stream entered the error state.

```
        std::cin.clear();
```

What if the user enters more than 2 integers? Should you keep reading from the line? Doing this, you'll need to make sure both values are extracted, even if one failed.  Could you `ignore()` the remaining input until end of line? You were only expecting two integers, so this is an option.

```
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

---

```
        a = std::stoi(_a);
        b = std::stoi(_b);
        std::cout << "You entered " << a << " and " << b << std::endl;
```

What happens if the extraction from `std::cin` fails? Either `_a`, `_b`, or both could be empty and [`std::stoi` will throw `std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) when an empty string is encountered.

`std::stoi` will truncate at the decimal separator and return the number to that point.  If you want to validate that the string represents an integer, you need to make sure `std::stoi` reads the full buffer.

```
        std::size_t last_pos_read;
        a = std::stoi(_a, std::address_of(last_pos_read));
        if (last_pos_read != _a.length()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not an integer.");
        }
```

Inexperience aside, the big lesson you should take from this review is to test! Test inputs of type integer (negatives, zero, positives, 16/32/64bit values), floating point (representable/nonrepresentable values), string/containers (empty/nonempty, small/large sizes). Test failures at different times, like an immediate failure or a failure after a successful loop.